# Jquery Image Slider Not Working on Mobile

Tags: jquery

I have been noticing some strange behavior with a new website I've been working on.  Essentially, I have a landing page which has a large banner image as the background which fades into other images every five seconds using Jquery.  On computers, the fading sequence works brilliantly, but the images never show up when viewing it on a mobile device (iphone, ipad, etc).  I originally thought it had something to do with the screen size of the viewing device (which was causing the images not to show up on an iphone)... however, this issue appears to happen on the ipad as well, so I'm not sure if screen resolution is actually the problem.

The code I'm using is a slight modification of an [online tutorial](http://www.webdevtuts.net/coding/create-a-full-background-image-slider-using-jquery/).  Basically, here is the html code:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img class="active" src="image1.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1" />
    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
    <img src="image3.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
    <img src="image4.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 4" />
    <img src="image5.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 5" />
</div>
```

And the Jquery code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    // uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

    // var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
    // var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
    // var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});

</script>
```

There is also a bit of CSS code, but I'm not entirely sure this would be causing the issue.  Nonetheless:

```
#slideshow_content {
  top: 50%;
  position: fixed;
}
#slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
#slideshow IMG {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 8;
  opacity: 0.0;
}
#slideshow IMG.active {
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
#slideshow IMG.last-active {
  z-index: 9;
}
#slideshow img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
```

Also, the link to the website I'm working on which has this issue can be found at: [www.liftarchitects.com](http://www.liftarchitects.com)

Comment: it's possible that some of the CSS you use is not known by the browser of the mobile device - have you tried simply showing and hiding the image without any animations or opacity changes to see if that works at all?

Comment: images working fine for me on my galaxy s3 chrome browser.. however the default android browser does not load the images

Comment: On the other hand.. you should really have a different view for mobile.. loading those images will murder people's data really fast.. I see the "About" page already loads in a mobile friendly way.. i suggest you do the same for mobile. run your website through http://validator.w3.org/mobile/ and you will see that around 20kb is the recommended size for a mobile page

Comment: As a follow up... how would you create a mobile-friendly page?  The reason all of the other pages work generally well on mobile is because I'm using Squarespace as my underlying framework.  However, I've gone in and added a bunch of javascript in order to customize the look and feel of the site.  The main landing page is completely done in javascript (by me)... so this is why this one doesn't necessarily load in a mobile friendly way, where as the others are part of a squarespace template and do load correctly.